# Can I force my bootloader to load windows 7 instead of Asus Express Gate Cloud

Tags: windows-7, boot, power, bootloader, netbook

I have an ASUS netbook that I dropped recently and now the power button isnt working. The only way I can boot up is by booting into Asus Express Gate Cloud (which is a different button) then pressing "switch OS" to boot into windows.

I was wondering if there was a way that I force that button to boot into windows rather than the Gate Cloud?

Thanks.

Comment: You may try in the BIOS settings. Reboot from Windows and then try `F1-F12` keys and `del`. One of them should allow you to access them. This needs to be done quickly after computer power-on, before Windows startup.

Comment: @Levans Nothing in the BIOS about it. Can only change the drive it boots from, which i only have one of.